# Debugging and Running Groovy scripts in IntelliJ when USER.HOME is on a network disk

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

I have a Windows 7 where user.home is mapped to an attached network disk. Also I've installed IntelliJ 12.1.4 and Groovy 2.1.5.

The first problem I had was that IntellyJ was unable to compile any project at all stating that it can not access ....\data file in config directory that was on the network disk, but that was finally solved by modifying the idea.properties file. All paths that have user.home string in them were pointed directly to the network attached disk\directory. After that all projects were successfully rebuild but then another problem appeared: IntelliJ could not debug or run Groovy scripts. The menu items(Debug "groovyscript name" and Run "groovyscritp name") simply disappear after project indexing is complete.

The question is:
Is there a way to configure Groovy running/debuging withing IntelliJ that is configured with user.home directory set on a network attached disk?

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual link to the network drive instead of pointing to it directly....

```
mklink <virtualDirName> \\network-path /d
```

If you run into permissions/privilege issues, see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/210824/creating-a-symbolic-link-to-mapped-network-drive-in-windows):